# How does Python hash itertools.count()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, python-itertools

I am trying to understand the underlying mechanics behind `hash(itertools.count(x, y))`.

I am not used to looking deeply into CPython implementations, but I noticed that in `itertoolsmodule.c` the [`static PyTypeObject count_type` has `0` for `tp_hash`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L4345).

I am assuming that this means that it does not implement `hash` in C. So, how does it get taken care of? Is there a Python object for the C binding `itertools.count` that implements `__hash__`?

On another note, what happens behind the scene such that

```py
itertools.count(0, 5) != itertools.count(0, 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just inherits the default identity-based `__hash__` and `__eq__` from `object`.

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_hash) for `tp_hash`:

> Inheritance:
>
> Group: tp_hash, tp_richcompare
>
> This field is inherited by subtypes together with tp_richcompare: a subtype inherits both of tp_richcompare and tp_hash, when the subtype’s tp_richcompare and tp_hash are both NULL.

Since `tp_hash` and `tp_richcompare` are both statically initialized to `0`, `PyType_Ready` will [copy those fields](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L5312-L5322) from the base class, which defaults to `object`.

Comment: I see, so anytime `tp_hash` or `tp_richcompare` are NULL then object's `tp_hash` and `tp_richcompare` are used. Thanks! Then I guess the second part of my question can be answered by looking into object's `tp_hash`?